# Open Source Publishing?

Tags: fiction, self-publishing

If an author is not concerned about making money from her story, but rather would like to publish the story to protect the story from copy right yet allow others to read and review the story for critical improvement, is there such an open source website or facility that promotes such a peer review environment?

Comment: When you say "read and review," do you mean like a wiki, where anyone can edit?  Or do you mean like a web-enabled version of TrackChanges, where anyone can suggest changes and/or insert comments keyed to the text?  Or do you just want reviews/comments, separate from the text?

Comment: Publishing doesn't protect it from copyright. You need to register the work to get copyright protection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an ebook and distribute it through Amazon's [Kindle Direct Publishing](https://kdp.amazon.com/) (or other ebook selling platforms) for $0.

---

Note:

Amazon KDP allows to give away your book for free for some limited time, after that you have to sell it for at least $0.99. But you can publish it for free elsewhere, and since Amazon always wants to have the cheapes prices, once you report that your book is available for free elsewhere, you can lower your price to free on Amazon, too. I never tried this, just read about it in forums and blogs. Google to find a more detailed how to. Of course you can always ignore Amazon and just use other platforms, but Amazon has the widest reach, so I would try to be on there, if I could.

Also:

Don't be hasty and throw away your idea just yet. Take some time to evaluate all options, let some experienced readers read it and give you feedback (find bloggers doing reviews in your genre and ask them for feedback), if they are even half positive, either educate yourself to write well or find a co-author, etc. You can always publish your book free, but maybe some better ideas come along in the next weeks or months.

Comment: Thanks for the additional notes. I was able to speak with the second English professor today. She stated she was engaged in the characters and took notice that the document was more of sample summary of world build then an actual well crafted story. She did say that there is potential in the story. I like the idea to wait, practice, learn, revise, evaluate approach. It is too early to rush to conclusions. Thanks. I am in an unusual position where I am not financially dependent on the success of the story, which puts me in a position to buy time for a more polished work.

Comment: Sounds good. If you want to stay within your creation instead of inventing something new, you could take one small event in your world and develop it into a story. Or write one scene or chapter. It does not matter how many pages this has, just that the whole thing is limited, and that you don't focus on developing the huge arch, but on how the characters think, their inner conflicts, the small scale development of the events. Take your favourite book and look at it: what is told on one page? What do the protagonists say? How do they say it? Stuff like that. Then try doing that.

Comment: Isaac Asimov published several of his best sci-fi books originally as separate (but related) short stories in sci-fi mags.  Later he collected them, did some revising, and published them as books.  "I, Robot" would be the best example.  Many of Asimov's peers worked similarly.

Answer (score 0):

github.com, gitlab.com. They offer to create a license file for you. I use non-copyleft licenses like MIT, BSD or Apache.